# How do I tell matplotlib that I am done with a plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The following code plots to two [PostScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript) (.ps) files, but the second one contains both lines.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

plt.subplot(111)
x = [1,10]
y = [30, 1000]
plt.loglog(x, y, basex=10, basey=10, ls="-")
plt.savefig("first.ps")


plt.subplot(111)
x = [10,100]
y = [10, 10000]
plt.loglog(x, y, basex=10, basey=10, ls="-")
plt.savefig("second.ps")
```

How can I tell matplotlib to start afresh for the second plot?

Comment: as a point of style, there's no need to use subplot when you only have one plot per figure.

Comment: I'm confused when do I use `plt.clf()` vs `plt.cla()`? I have a general function that saves open figures (makes no assumptions, does not take the fig object) and I want inside of it to have a way to completely close everything after it saves so that when I start producing the next plot the next call to the save function doesn't save the same plot again by accident. Is it ok if I ALWAYS run `plt.clf()` vs `plt.cla()` in my save function no matter what? Does it always close everything? `plt.show()` did do that but in cluster that can lead to bugs.

Comment: perhaps useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661790/difference-between-plt-close-and-plt-clf

Comment: did you try `plt.close()`? that worked for me and made sure I didn't accidentally save the same plot multiple times.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can use `figure` to create a new plot, for example, or use `close` after the first plot.

Comment: The pyplot tutorial does mention clf() in the "multiple figures" section. Note that if you just create a new plot with figure() without closing the old one with close() (even if you close the GUI window), pyplot retains a reference to your old figure, which may look like a memory leak.

Comment: You can use plt.close()/pylab.close() to remove all old figures

Comment: After first plot, do you mean after `plt.savefig("first.ps")`?

Comment: @JouniK.Seppänen Just to add to your comment, Python will by default warn you if you open many figures: "RuntimeWarning: More than 20 figures have been opened.".

Comment: Do you have to call `plt.close()` or `plt.figure()`? Your answer is much more helpful, it's self-contained with exact code -- especially if it's one single command.

Comment: Also note that you can call `plt.close("all")` to close *all* figure windows, not just the current one.

Answer (score 222):

There is a clear figure command, and it should do it for you:

```
plt.clf()
```

If you have multiple subplots in the same figure

```
plt.cla()
```

clears the current axes.

Comment: Thanks!  If you are using the PDF backend (which allows you to save multiple plots) you will need to call this after each call to plt.save()

Comment: In my case, plt.clf() was sufficient to clear the figure but insufficient to stop memory leaks, but first calling plt.close() stopped the memory leak. Python 2.7, matplotlib 1.1.1rc1 (ubuntu 12.04). FYI.

Comment: I'm confused when do I use `plt.clf()` vs `plt.cla()`? I have a general function that saves open figures (makes no assumptions, does not take the fig object) and I want inside of it to have a way to completely close everything after it saves so that when I start producing the next plot the next call to the save function doesn't save the same plot again by accident. Is it ok if I ALWAYS run `plt.clf()` vs `plt.cla()` in my save function no matter what? Does it always close everything? `plt.show()` did do that but in cluster that can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 38):

As stated from @DavidCournapeau, use `figure()`.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

plt.figure()
x = [1,10]
y = [30, 1000]
plt.loglog(x, y, basex=10, basey=10, ls="-")
plt.savefig("first.ps")


plt.figure()
x = [10,100]
y = [10, 10000]
plt.loglog(x, y, basex=10, basey=10, ls="-")
plt.savefig("second.ps")
```

Or `subplot(121)` / `subplot(122)` for the same plot, different position.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab

plt.subplot(121)
x = [1,10]
y = [30, 1000]
plt.loglog(x, y, basex=10, basey=10, ls="-")

plt.subplot(122)
x = [10,100]
y = [10, 10000]
plt.loglog(x, y, basex=10, basey=10, ls="-")
plt.savefig("second.ps")
```

Comment: you should still use `plt.clf()`, figures are held in memory until explicitly closed

Comment: where is your `plt.close()`?

Answer (score 14):

Just enter `plt.hold(False)` before the first plt.plot, and you can stick to your original code.

Comment: in matplotlib==2.0.2, I get this message: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: pyplot.hold is deprecated.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Matplotlib interactively, for example in a web application, (e.g. ipython) you maybe looking for

```
plt.show()
```

instead of `plt.close()` or `plt.clf()`.

Comment: you just saved me a bunch of time I didn't have to lose

Answer (score 6):

From the source code of [matplotlib.pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib/pyplot.html#figure), under the `figure()` documentation:

> ```
> If you are creating many figures, make sure you explicitly call
>     `.pyplot.close` on the figures you are not using, because this will
>     enable pyplot to properly clean up the memory.
> ```

So, as others have said, use `plt.close()` on each figure when you're done with it, and you'll be good to go!

NOTE: if you create the figure via `f = plt.figure()`, you can close it via `plt.close( f )` instead of `f.close()`.

Answer (score 2):

If none of them are working then check this.. say if you have x and y arrays of  data along respective axis. Then check in which cell(jupyter) you have initialized x and y to empty. This is because , maybe you are appending data to x and y without re-initializing them. So plot has old data too. So check that..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `plt.close()`? that worked for me and made sure I didn't accidentally save the same plot multiple times.

Code:

```
def save_to(root: Path, plot_name: str = 'plot', close: bool = True):
    """
    Assuming there is a plot in display, saves it to local users desktop users desktop as a png, svg & pdf.

    note:
        - ref on closing figs after saving: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741877/how-do-i-tell-matplotlib-that-i-am-done-with-a-plot
        - clf vs cla https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661790/difference-between-plt-close-and-plt-clf
    """
    root: Path = root.expanduser()
    plt.savefig(root / f'{plot_name}.png')
    plt.savefig(root / f'{plot_name}.svg')
    plt.savefig(root / f'{plot_name}.pdf')
    if close:
        # plt.clf()
        # plt.cla()
        plt.close()
```

in my ultimate utils lib: https://github.com/brando90/ultimate-utils