# How do I create a second (new) plot, then later plot on the old one?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I want to plot data, then create a new figure and plot data2, and finally come back to the original plot and plot data3, kinda like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

x = arange(5)
y = np.exp(5)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y)

z = np.sin(x)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, z)

w = np.cos(x)
plt.figure("""first figure""") # Here's the part I need
plt.plot(x, w)
```

FYI [How do I tell matplotlib that I am done with a plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/741877/how-do-i-tell-matplotlib-that-i-am-done-with-a-plot) does something similar, but not quite! It doesn't let me get access to that original plot.

Answer (score 194, accepted):

If you find yourself doing things like this regularly it may be worth investigating the object-oriented interface to matplotlib. In your case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.exp(x)
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax1.set_title("Axis 1 title")
ax1.set_xlabel("X-label for axis 1")

z = np.sin(x)
fig2, (ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1) # two axes on figure
ax2.plot(x, z)
ax3.plot(x, -z)

w = np.cos(x)
ax1.plot(x, w) # can continue plotting on the first axis
```

It is a little more verbose but it's much clearer and easier to keep track of, especially with several figures each with multiple subplots.

Comment: I prefer the object oriented approach as when I anticipate having many figures, it will be easier to keep track of them by using names rather than numbers. Thanks!

Comment: But how can one change the label and axis limits with this approach. If I use `ax1.ylabel` it says that it is not found. Same with `fig1.ylabel` ...

Comment: @GeorgeDatseris The syntax is a little different. It's `ax1.set_xlabel("your x label")`, `ax1.set_ylabel("your y label")`, and `ax1.set_title("your title")`.

Comment: why did you use 111 ?

Comment: @yashSodha - that's a matlab-style specification of number of subplots (rows, col, index). But it's much easier now to use `plt.subplots(nrows, ncols)`. Have updated the example.

Comment: I upvoted you, cauz you're answer worked for me, thanks! But could you please add images to your answer, maybe more examples with different parameters? I mean, I had to look up the documentation to find best fit for my solution. Would have been really helpful to add images with different effects.

Answer (score 182):

When you call `figure`, simply number the plot.

```
x = arange(5)
y = np.exp(5)
plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(x, y)

z = np.sin(x)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, z)

w = np.cos(x)
plt.figure(0) # Here's the part I need
plt.plot(x, w)
```

Edit: Note that you can number the plots however you want (here, starting from `0`) but if you don't provide figure with a number at all when you create a new one, the automatic numbering will start at `1` ("Matlab Style" according to the docs).

Comment: This appears to work in matplotlib's interactive mode, while the figure() ... add_subplot() method does not. Thanks!

Comment: @SebMa Please don't change the code without understanding it. This answer was specifically about passing a number to `figure`, which you removed. The other things you changed were copied from the original post and not mistakes in my answer.

Comment: @agf Hi, I removed the `1` inside `plt.figure(1)` because I thought the number was auto incremented and therefore not necessary. Sorry.

Comment: But then only figure(0) gets the title and legend

Answer (score 25):

However, numbering starts at `1`, so:

```
x = arange(5)
y = np.exp(5)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y)

z = np.sin(x)
plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(x, z)

w = np.cos(x)
plt.figure(1) # Here's the part I need, but numbering starts at 1!
plt.plot(x, w)
```

Also, if you have multiple axes on a figure, such as subplots, use the `axes(h)` command where `h` is the handle of the desired axes object to focus on that axes.

(don't have comment privileges yet, sorry for new answer!)

Comment: `0` works, _automatic_ numbering just start at `1`, if you don't give it a number at all.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer here says to use the *object oriented interface* (`matplotlib`) but the answer itself incoporates some of the *MATLAB-style interface* (`matplotib.pyplot`).

It is possible to use **solely the OOP** method, if you like that sort of thing:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.exp(x)
first_figure      = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
first_figure_axis = first_figure.add_subplot()
first_figure_axis.plot(x, y)

z = np.sin(x)
second_figure      = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
second_figure_axis = second_figure.add_subplot()
second_figure_axis.plot(x, z)

w = np.cos(x)
first_figure_axis.plot(x, w)

display(first_figure) # Jupyter
display(second_figure)
```

This gives the user manual control over the figures, and avoids problems associated with `pyplot`'s internal state supporting only a single figure.

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to plot separate frame for each iteration could be:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
for grp in list_groups:
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(grp)
        plt.show()
```

Then python will plot different frames.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what the OP asked for, and what is required when using the original interface.

Answer (score 1):

One way I found after some struggling is creating a function which gets data_plot matrix, file name and order as parameter to create boxplots from the given data in the ordered figure (different orders = different figures) and save it under the given file_name.

```
def plotFigure(data_plot,file_name,order):
    fig = plt.figure(order, figsize=(9, 6))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    bp = ax.boxplot(data_plot)
    fig.savefig(file_name, bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
```