# Pandas DataFrame plot - separate graphics with dot notation

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Example DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Amount':[10,20,30,40,50],
                        'Get':[111,222,333,444,555],
                        'Sum':[100,200,300,400,500]},
                  index=['Sun', 'Mon', 'The', 'Wed', 'Tue'])
```

Contents of **df** is now:

```
     Amount Get Sum
Sun     10  111 100
Mon     20  222 200
The     30  333 300
Wed     40  444 400
Tue     50  555 500
```

When I try draw two separate plots (**skip second column 'Get'**) with dot notation like:

```
df['Amount'].plot()
df['Sum'].plot()
```

or in loop (in case I need filter some columns):

```
for i in range(df.shape[1]):
    if df.columns[i] in ['Amount', 'Sum']:
        df[df.columns[i]].plot()
```

I Received same graphic(figure):

[plots image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N40aF.png)

But I need separate them to different figures. Yes I know I can create separated figure objects, but it is too complicated for simple case and must exist some separator for my case above (dot notated for DataFrame).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell Matplotlib to create a second (new) plot, then later plot on the old one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916978/how-do-i-tell-matplotlib-to-create-a-second-new-plot-then-later-plot-on-the-o)

Comment: @NathanFurnal is too complicated for my case. Yes I know how to draw plots using sublotss and figure objects. But dot notated case looks more simple and must have some separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.plot(subplots=True);
```

[image]

Separate x-axis:

```
df.plot(subplots=True, sharex=False);
```

[image]

Comment: Cool! One more new useful case for me! But In this case both graphics have same common X axis. Maybe possible fully separate them to independent images?

Comment: @Obelix add, `sharex=False` as  parameter in plot.

Comment: thanks. But how about if columns in DataFrame about 100? I mean, how to control\filter which ones use to show in this subplots? Why I ask to separate plots.. I think I can filter some columns in loop to show only those which I need. My main question doesn't reveal this case..

Comment: Good question.   I am not sure that can be done.  I'll do a little research and see.  If I find out anything, I'll post an update to this solution.