# How to Iterate or Loop the Python Script for the range

Tags: python-3.x

I have built a python script to plot an image file, it works fine. When I want to plot multiple image files within a range, I am able to create multiple image files. The issue I am facing - the first image files comes out fine. The second, third and there after all image files are overlapped with the previous image files. What is that I am doing wrong. Appreciate some help, I am new to Python.

```
df4 = ((df3 + 1).cumprod() - 1)

for row_no in range(2, 10):
  df5 = df4.iloc[:row_no,:]

  rcParams['figure.figsize']=25,10
  plt.scatter(df5.mean(), df5.std())
  plt.vlines(df5['SPY'].mean(), ymin = -0.01, ymax = 0.10, colors = 'blue') 
  plt.hlines(df5['SPY'].std(), xmin = -0.10, xmax = 0.10, colors = 'blue') 
  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.xlabel('Expected returns')
  plt.ylabel('Risk')
  plt.title("Watchlist Today Performance")
  plt.xlim([-0.1, 0.1])
  plt.ylim([-0.01, 0.1])

  for label, x, y in zip(df5.columns, df5.mean(), df5.std()):
    #plt.annotate(label, xy = (x, y), xytext = (20, -20), textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom', bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'red', alpha = 0.5), arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))
    plt.annotate(label, xy = (x, y), xytext = (20, -20), textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom', bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'red', alpha = 0.5))

  plt.savefig('/content/drive/MyDrive/Images/jan26/image.png')

  i = 0
  while os.path.exists("/content/drive/MyDrive/Images/jan26/image-%s.png" % i):
    i += 1

  with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Images/jan26/image.png', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

  with open('/content/drive/MyDrive/Images/jan26/image-%s.png' % i, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

First Image file
[image]
Fifth Image File
[image]
Final Image File
[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6916978/7696914

Comment: Not helpful, need more clarity.

Comment: What part is unclear? It seems like you just need to add `plt.figure(row_no)` to the beginning of your loop so that each scatter plot is made in a new figure.

Comment: Works good Sir, thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell Matplotlib to create a second (new) plot, then later plot on the old one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6916978/how-do-i-tell-matplotlib-to-create-a-second-new-plot-then-later-plot-on-the-o)

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.