# Matplotlib creates multiple figures after using subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

**Problem:**
First, I create figure *A* with [`matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). After plotting the data, the figure will be saved.
Next, I call `matplotlib.pyplot.clf`, before I create a second figure *B* (also with `matplotlib.pyplot.subplots`). However, this time I use `matplotlib.pyplot.show` to display fig *B*. Unfortunately matplotlib creates two windows, one for *A* and one for *B*, instead only one for *B* (see [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMIcl.png)).

**Qustion**:
Is there a way to block the window of figure *A*?

**System information**
OS: Windows 10 (64bit)
Python version: 3.7.3
Matplotlib version: 3.1.0

**Sample code**

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 100)

# Creation of figure A
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax0.plot(x, np.sin(x))
ax1.plot(x, np.cos(x))
fig.savefig('test.pdf')
# Removing current figure (should be figure A)
plt.clf()

# Creating second figure B
fig2, (ax_0, ax_1) = plt.subplots(2, 1)
ax_0.plot(x, np.sin(x))
ax_1.plot(x, np.cos(x))

plt.show() # Creates two windows, although I am only interested in fig2
```

Comment: try using `plt.close()`

Comment: Thanks it works. I did not know about `plt.close`. This is an informative post explaining the difference betweeen `plt.clf()` and `plt.close`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16661790/difference-between-plt-close-and-plt-clf