# matplotlib: releasing memory after plot is done

Tags: python, memory-management, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to know the correct way to release memory after a plot is done since I'm getting a `RuntimeError: Could not allocate memory for image` error when plotting multiple images in a loop.

Currently I have the following commands in another code to supposedly do just that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# The code
.....

# Make plot
fig = plt.figure()
# Plotting stuff.
plt.imshow(...)
plt.plot(...)
plt.scatter(...)

# Save plot to file.
plt.savefig(...)

# Release memory.
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

A comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8228808/1391441) states that the correct syntax is actually `plt.close(fig)` but the highest voted answer [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742062/1391441) says that `plt.clf()` is enough and doesn't mention `.close`.

The questions are: what is(are) the correct command(s) to release memory after the plot is saved to file? Do I need both `.clf` and `.close` or is one of them enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to suggest for you an alternate approach.  Note that `imshow` returns a handle for you.  Grab a reference on this, and use the `set_data` method on that object for subsequent iterations.

```
>>> h = plt.imshow(np.zeros([480, 640]))
>>> h
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x47a03d0>
>>> for img in my_imgs:
...     h.set_data(img)  #etc
```

Comment: Would you mind expanding your answer a bit? What if I don't use `imshow` in my plots? What does the `set_data` call do?

Comment: You haven't shown how you plot your images, so `plt.imshow` was just an educated guess.  `set_data` will update the `AxesImage` object in this case, with new data, rather than creating a new image object which seems to be giving you memory problems.

Comment: Thanks @wim. I do make use of `imshow` occasionally but not exclusively. I also use `plt.plot()` and `plt.scatter()`, so I'm not sure how this could be applied to those cases, I'll update the question to make this more clear.

Comment: The same goes for each of those cases, you should keep the references returned by `plot` and `scatter` as well, and they will also have `set_data` method which you can use when iterating.