# Reset variables after each loop

Tags: python, loops, variables, reset

I have multiple csv files with two columns of values like this:

[image]

I use the following python code to calculate the R2 value and plot these data.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for filepath in glob.iglob(r'*.csv'):
    print(filepath)
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    x_values = df["LMP"]
    y_values = df["LMP_old"]

    correlation_matrix = np.corrcoef(x_values, y_values)
    correlation_xy = correlation_matrix[0,1]
    r_squared = correlation_xy**2
    plt.scatter(x_values,y_values)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted LMP')
    plt.ylabel("Actual LMP")
    plt.title(r_squared)
    plt.xlim(20000, 26000)
    plt.ylim(20000, 26000)
    x = np.linspace(20000, 26000)
    plt.plot(x, x, linestyle='solid')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(filepath+".png")
    print(r_squared)
    with open(filepath+".txt", "w") as text_file:
         print(f"{r_squared}", file=text_file)
```

But I found the `x_values` and `y_values` will not be reseted after each loop, but will remember the values from last loop and keep accumulating. What command is needed so that `x_values` and `y_values` will be independent/reseted after each loop?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What makes you think that `x_values` and `y_values` are not being reset?  Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @0x5453I found the data from all previous csv files will be plotted together with the present one.

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [How do I tell matplotlib that I am done with a plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/741877/3282436)

Comment: @0x5453 Thanks. I find the solution there. Just add```plt.close()``` after     ```plt.savefig(filepath+".png")```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for filepath in glob.iglob(r'*.csv'):
    print(filepath)
    df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
    x_values = df["LMP"]
    y_values = df["LMP_old"]

    correlation_matrix = np.corrcoef(x_values, y_values)
    correlation_xy = correlation_matrix[0,1]
    r_squared = correlation_xy**2
    plt.scatter(x_values,y_values)
    plt.xlabel('Predicted LMP')
    plt.ylabel("Actual LMP")
    plt.title(r_squared)
    plt.xlim(20000, 26000)
    plt.ylim(20000, 26000)
    x = np.linspace(20000, 26000)
    plt.plot(x, x, linestyle='solid')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig(filepath+".png")
    
    plt.close()  # Adding this code solves the issue.

    print(r_squared)
    with open(filepath+".txt", "w") as text_file:
         print(f"{r_squared}", file=text_file)
```